# Is a compile-time error generated as C# code is being written or when the program is being compiled?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, compile-time

Been looking for online sources (especially MS documentations) that clearly say when a compile-time error is generated. Sadly I have not found any. I do know that a compile-time error is generated because of incorrect syntax or incorrect semantics in C# code.

Is a compile-time error generated during program development (as I am writing C# code) or is a compile-time error at compile time (when the C# program is being compiled)?

Please include any credible C# MS documentation if possible. Perhaps there is one I have not yet read.

Comment: Visual Studio can detect many compile-time errors while you are writing your code.  See those little red squigglies under your code?   In a sense, Visual Studio pre-compiles your code while you are writing it, in order to show you those errors.  You can also get compile-time errors when you do a build.  You can see those in the Errors window.  No need for documentation; you haven't run the program yet, so by definition these are not runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

You’re asking the wrong question,
What does it mean when they are generated? obviously when you write something that can’t compile..
Compile time errors are errors that interferes compilation, it’s another question to ask, when those errors can be detected, obviously they will fail compilation, but can be detected prior to compilation. Almost every IDE today can recognize compile time errors before compilation.